# Is it possible to run multiplayer games servers with the help of the cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, multiplayer

There are some countries who does not have their own servers for a particular games. so, in order to play those games online they have to connect to other countries servers. but, since AWS cloud services and servers are almost everywhere so why won't game developers use cloud services to provide servers in those countries or it's not possible to do so ?

Comment: You'll have to ask those companies. AWS has 24 regions worldwide at the moment, with 6 more announced. So, it's not quite "everywhere". I think you'll find that a lot of game developers _are_ using the cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud provides [game servers](https://cloud.google.com/game-servers) product, based on Agones and some features of Anthos. The purpose is the following:

*With a single control plane, you can manage fleet of Agones servers deployed on Google Cloud or elsewhere, on Kubernetes servers.*

Like this, if you want to deploy Agones servers in a country where google isn't present (but maybe AWS, Azure or a local Cloud Service, and even your own on-prem datacenter) you simply have to deploy Agones on Kubernetes Cluster and to register it on Google CLoud game servers product and then you manage your new region as a "Google Cloud region". (Take care of network capacity, every cloud provider can't propose the same fiber network quality as Google)